# Данные из базы Mysql в Highcharts?

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

Из базы вытягивается информация дата - количество, и импортируется в *Highcharts*, как сделать запрос?

```
  <option value="">Select Category</option>
  <?php 
    $dbconfig = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
    $sql_query="SELECT * FROM category order by category_name asc";
    $result=mysqli_query($dbconfig,$sql_query);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row['category_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['category_name'];?></option>
    <?php 
    } 
    ?>
</select>
<select name="domains" id="domains" class="form-control"></select>
<select name="projects" id="projects" class="form-control"></select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй print json_encode ($row, etc.) и в качестве источника данных указать этот php-файл